# How to define a priority queue with four values in c++?

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue, std-pair

when we have two values like ID and Marks of a student and we want to put it in a queue we define the priority queue in the following way.

```
priority_queue<pair<int,int> > queue;
```

Let us say, that we have four values to put it into a queue. ie., I want all the three values as a single entity in the queue and I will define my own comaprator based on the three values. I'm new to STL and I could not find appropriate way of doing this.

Comment: Three, or four, ... what?

Comment: If you have a set of values that are closely related, why not use a structure to hold them?

Comment: If there are just three or four valid values, you should consider using an enum instead of an int to help make things clearer. Also, instead of a priority queue, possibly you might be better of using a map or multimap, which also provides ordering and can quite easily be used for queue-like behaviour.

Comment: Put everything you want a `single entity` to contain (three values) in a `struct`. And I recommend you don't use `std::pair` because it is very undescriptive of what it contains. I would use another `struct`.

Comment: It wold be easier for someone to craft an answer if you were more explicit about exactly what information you want each item to contain that you want to put in your queue.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. following your suggestions,I'm thinking of putting all in a structure and using a comparator on the struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have [std::tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) for such cases. And you write a comparator just like you would write it for a pair.

Comment: I generally use simple structs because of their namedness. Is there much of a downside to this?

Comment: @Goodies, personally, I can't even come up with the case where I'd use a tuple instead of a struct. So in my opinion there are drawbacks in tuple not in structs.

Comment: @Goodies a downside is *requiring* inventing the comparator.  You can avoid implementing a fair bit of code going that route if the standard library versions are sufficient. [Trivial example here](http://ideone.com/FCYcpR) with no user-defined comparator nor operators implemented. Regardless, for clarity and understanding, someone new would likely take the struct-road if for no other reason than ease of understanding.

Comment: @WhozCraig std::tie makes it easy to write a comparator

Answer (score 0):

Joachim's idea of a struct is a good idea. I would probably take it one step further make the struct into its own class (let's call it DataNode). Then you can queue and dequeue the data node objects (each pointing to its own data) rather than passing the raw data into the queue.

Comment: `struct`, `class`: same thing in C++.

Comment: A struct is not exactly like a class, tho it is very similar.  The advantage (in the case of transactions) of a  class is that it has its own namespace and can contain its own methods for manipulating the data, if it is needed.  Also, because it has its own namespace, the datanode could be created,  passed or pointed to by other classes, independently.  Not knowing what it is being used for makes it hard to know which would be best. That being the case,  I default to the most versatile/modular option. Just my two cents.

Comment: For all intents and purposes, there is no difference. Certainly none of the stuff you mentioned it true. You can define exactly the same types using either. The only differences are the *default* member access and inheritance being `private`/`public` for `class`/`struct` respectively. You have some serious misconceptions that you should dispell!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <queue> 
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

struct Student
{   
    Student(string name, int id, int marks): name(name), id(id), marks(marks){}
    string name;
    int id;
    int marks;
};
struct DereferenceCompareNode : public std::binary_function<Student, Student, bool>
{
     bool operator()(const Student& lhs, const Student& rhs) const
     {
                if (lhs.id == rhs.id)
                {
                    return lhs.marks >rhs.marks;
                }
                else
                {
                    return lhs.id > rhs.id;
                }
     }
};
int main()
{
    priority_queue<Student, vector<Student>, DereferenceCompareNode> a;
    a.push(Student("yang", 1000, 98));
    a.push(Student("yang", 1000, 75));
    a.push(Student("zhang", 999, 98));
    a.push(Student("zhang", 999, 100));
    while( !a.empty() ){
        Student top = a.top();
            printf("%s, %d, %d\n", top.name.c_str(), top.id, top.marks);
                a.pop();
     }
    cout<<"hello world"<<endl;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
wangyang@wangyang ~ $ ./a.out 
zhang, 999, 98
zhang, 999, 100
yang, 1000, 75
yang, 1000, 98
```

I think you can use this code,
For usage of `queue`, please refer http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: @anil Note that all that [`binary_function` stuff is deprecated](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/binary_function). There are far easier ways of doing this since C++11 (or in C++03 using libraries such as boost.)